# Trying to select script tags from a jQuery ajax get response

Tags: jquery

I'm on page A. A link is clicked, and I'm loading in the DOM via jQuery get from page B. Inside page B's DOM are multiple dynamically-generated script tags with the class "dataScript" along with a bunch of other script tags that I don't want anything to do with.

The only thing I want from that DOM are the .dataScript tags, which I then want to insert into a div with an ID of "scriptOutput" into the DOM of page A. This won't work if the element with the class of "dataScript" is a script tag. Only if it's some other tag, such as a "div" tag. Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

Page A:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Page A</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function() {
 $("#ajaxJsLink").click(function() {
  $.get("pageB.html", function(data) {
   var scriptElements = $(data).find(".dataScript").contents();
   console.log(scriptElements);
   $(scriptElements).each(function(index) {
    $("#scriptOutput").append($(this).html());
   });
  });
  return false;
 });
 $("#ajaxDivsLink").click(function() {
  $.get("pageB.html", function(data) {
   var scriptElements = $(data).find(".dataDiv").contents();
   console.log(scriptElements);
   $(scriptElements).each(function(index) {
    $("#divOutput").append($(this).html());
   });
  });
  return false;
 });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>This is page A.</p>
<hr />
<p>
<a href="pageB.html" id="ajaxJsLink">Get JavaScript from Page B.</a><br />
<a href="pageB.html" id="ajaxDivsLink">Get Divs from Page B.</a>
</p>
<hr />
<div id="scriptOutput">
 <h2>Script Output</h2>
</div>
<div id="divOutput">
 <h2>Div Output</h2>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Page B:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Page B</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>This is page B.</p>
<div id="scripts">
 <script type="text/javascript" class="dataScript">
  function someFunction() {
   alert("I am");
  }
 </script>
 <script type="text/javascript" class="dataScript">
  function anotherFunction() {
   alert("Javascript");
  }
 </script>
</div>
<div id="divs">
 <div class="dataDiv">
  <div>
   function someFunction() {
    alert("I am");
   }
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="dataDiv">
  <div>
   function anotherFunction() {
    alert("Html");
   }
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I've tried appending .contents(), .html(), and .text() for the .dataScript content, but nothing seems to work. Thanks for your consideration in looking at/answering my questions. I appreciate your help!

---

**UPDATE:**

In case anyone else is trying to do this, here is the less-than-elegant but fully-functional solution I ended up with:

Output javascript as regular text (no script tags) inside one div (with an ID and set to display:none) on Page B. Then on Page A, do the following inside the callback function of the get request:

```
var docHead = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]; //head of Page A
var newScript = document.createElement("script");
newScript.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
newScript.innerHTML = jQuery(data).find("#divWithPlainTextJs").text(); //insert plain text JS into script element
docHead.appendChild(newScript); //append script element to head of Page A
jQuery("#divWithPlainTextJs").remove(); //remove the plain text div and JS from the DOM
```

Thanks to Emmett for reminding me of the document.createElement method.

Comment: This could be because `class` is not a valid attribute on `<script>`: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.1

Comment: do you have any control over the contents of page B?

Comment: @Andrew That was my first guess too, but `.find("script")` doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: @Andrew Whitaker - yeah that was mostly for demo purposes i guess. another way i tried was putting a div around the script tags and then searching for script tags inside that div

Comment: @Ender - yes, I have complete control over both pages. I just can't put the JS into an external file because the JS I'm trying to load from page B is dynamically generated. But like I said, I can generate it in any way that will work I suppose.

Comment: @Emmet, @esvendsen - you need to use `.filter("script")`. See my answer below.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

jQuery doesn't actually append `<script>` elements to the DOM. Instead, it just evals the contents of the script. Since it isn't in the DOM, `$(data).find(".dataScript")` doesn't match anything.

If you really need the contents of the `<script>` tag, you could try using a regular expression to parse the ajax response.

Check out [Karl Swedberg's comment](http://api.jquery.com/append/#comment-61121802) for more info:

> All of jQuery's insertion methods use
>   a domManip function internally to
>   clean/process elements before and
>   after they are inserted into the DOM.
>   One of the things the domManip
>   function does is pull out any script
>   elements about to be inserted and run
>   them through an "evalScript routine"
>   rather than inject them with the rest
>   of the DOM fragment. It inserts the
>   scripts separately, evaluates them,
>   and then removes them from the DOM.
>
> I believe that one of the reasons
>   jQuery does this is to avoid
>   "Permission Denied" errors that can
>   occur in Internet Explorer when
>   inserting scripts under certain
>   circumstances. It also avoids
>   repeatedly inserting/evaluating the
>   same script (which could potentially
>   cause problems) if it is within a
>   containing element that you are
>   inserting and then moving around the
>   DOM.

Comment: interesting. it's strange though that i can't even select script elements. if i log the value of "data" to the console, the entire DOM of page B is returned, including script tags and such. so it's there, i just can't do anything with it?

Comment: @griswoldo Yea, basically. That's because jQuery is trying to select the `script` elements *from the DOM*. It is possible to add `<script>` elems to the DOM with plain ol javascript (`document.createElement('script')`), but this alone doesn't really trivialize what you're trying to do.

Comment: thanks - although not what I was hoping for, you answered my question.

Answer (score 3):

The main issues are... expecting the `<script>` elements to be children of `<div id='scripts'>`, and using `.find()` instead of `.filter()`.

When using jQuery's `$.get()` and `$.ajax()`, the returned `data` is a text string. When you place `data` in a jQuery wrapper, `$data = $(data)`, it's converted into an array: `[p, div#scripts, div#divs, div#dataDiv, <script.dataScript>, <script.dataScript>]`. Did you notice the `<script>` elements are no longer children of `<div id='scripts'>` but at the root? jQuery did that on purpose.

`$dataScripts = $data.filter('script.dataScripts')` will give us a collection we can now iterate through like so:

```
$dataScripts.each(function(i) {
    $('#scriptOutput').append($(this));
});
```

This will **evaluate** the scripts in `$dataScripts`, not insert them into the DOM like [@Emmett](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2749/emmett) mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

If you load the AJAX result like this:

```
function (data) {
 // the result is loaded in the variable 'data'
}
```

And then push it into a div like this:

```
function (data) {
 $("#someDiv").text(data);
}
```

The entire page including html tags will be placed as text so you can see the tags. You could trim the page to get only the scripts you want, but ask yourself is it is clever to do so.

The thing is... if you just save the script as an external .js file you could load it in ajax as text :)

Comment: I know that I can dump everything into a div, but trimming the page to get only the scripts I want is really the crux of my question. I need to use jQuery selectors to get the tags, but I don't know how to specify the document from which to select. Also, like I said above, I can't put the JS into an external file because it's being dynamically generated based on what page you're on, etc.

Comment: if it is dynamicly generated, just output the dynamically generated code in a var in jQuery too and you can output it anyway you want :)