# jquery select script node from get call

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to select a script node by id from a ajax get call.

```
<script id="jqgrid_js" type="text/javascript">
...
</script>
```

The get call:

```
            $.get(url, function(results){
              console.debug(results); //the jqgrid_js is included in the result
              console.debug($('#jqgrid_js')); //this returns the node from the actual page
              console.debug($('#jqgrid_js', results)); // in the result I can not select it
              var jqgrid_js = $('#jqgrid_js', results);
              //do the update
              $('#jqgrid_js').html(jqgrid_js); 
            }, "html");
```

I'm wondering why the same select statement does not return the node, whereas the node is definitely included in the "results" var.

Comment: The `context` cannot be a HTML string: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/

Comment: ok, and what do I have to change?

Answer (score 0):

Try turning this around and using `find` instead:

```
var jqgrid_js = $(results).find('#jqgrid_js');
```

Comment: does not change anything. In the meantime I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4430707/trying-to-select-script-tags-from-a-jquery-ajax-get-response ..