# get script element of ajax result in jQuery

Tags: jquery

So, we can use

```
jQuery.ajax({
  success: function(result){}
});
```

to make an Ajax request, and get the result.

Now, I found out that you can't select anything inside the head tag of the result. this simply fails:

```
jQuery( 'script', result )
```

but I can select div's and such. Why? How to get around this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trying to select script tags from a jQuery ajax get response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4430707/trying-to-select-script-tags-from-a-jquery-ajax-get-response)

Answer (score 1):

See [Trying to select script tags from a jQuery ajax get response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4430707/trying-to-select-script-tags-from-a-jquery-ajax-get-response)

Comment: I've been trying to use RegEx for this with no luck for hours. This should work but I don't know why it doesn't: <script>([^<\/script>])<\/script> which should select from script tag until it reaches the end of it. No luck with this either: <script>([.+]) it returns nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to get scripts is to use $.getScript() I say this only because it's the proper way to execute function after page has loaded.

[jQuery.getScript() - official page](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)

Answer (score 0):

The script does not get put on the page.  It gets eval'ed by jquery see: [Trying to select script tags from a jQuery ajax get response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4430707/trying-to-select-script-tags-from-a-jquery-ajax-get-response)

What I am trying to do is find out where on the page we were when the script was created (created from a tag).  Aurgh!