# jQuery.replaceWith doesn't take <script> tags

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, replacewith

I have an AJAX response that contains some HTML, including `<script>` elements.

This HTML should replace an existing element, but when I use:

```
$(element).replaceWith($(response))
```

I lose the script tags from it...

How can I insert the HTML exactly how it is sent?

Comment: You have to brake up the closing `</script>` in such a way as the browser won't immediately interpret it as a closing `</script>` tag. For instance, you often see it like `'</scr'+'ipt>'`.

Comment: @Jared Farrish: why not post that as an answer?

Comment: @JohnB - Because it's only a partial answer, more of a detail. Personally, I'd want to know more about what's going on. For instance, why not extract the `script` from the `<script>` tags, create a DOM script element, and insert the AJAX script into it? A technique needs to be suggested, I just don't know which one.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4430707/trying-to-select-script-tags-from-a-jquery-ajax-get-response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is from facebook's sample app. Insert `<div id="fb-root"></div>` in your document. The code requires jQuery to load up the script. In your case, replace `//connect...../all.js`' with the `<script>` elements.

```
(function() {
var e = document.createElement('script');
e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
e.async = true;
document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}());
```

Answer (score 3):

It will return a string!!

```
$.get("ajax.php")
     .success(function(returningHtmlString) {
          $(element).replaceWith(returningHtmlString);
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

See `jQuery.parseHTML( data [, context ] [, keepScripts ] )`

The following should work

```
var content = jQuery.parseHTML(response, document, true)
$(element).replaceWith(content)
```