# Querying for script elements from HTML text using jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm loading a page via `$.ajax()` and inserting *parts* of the result into the corresponding parts of the page:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/whole_page.html',
  success: function (data, status, xhr) {
    $result = $(xhr.responseText);
    $('#menu').html($('#menu', $result).html());
    $('#content').html($('#content', $result).html());
  }
});
```

Works like a charm, but I've run into a problem.

Now my pages contain some page-specific JS which must be executed when the result is fetched and inserted. As far as I can tell, jQuery won't return `script` elements if you construct a jQuery object from HTML text and query against it (I've [made a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kaen/rEWYz/5/) to demonstrate). So, I have no way of selectively inserting only the scripts I want via jQuery.

So it would seem that I've got to pull the `script` elements from response text myself. Essentially, I'm looking for the right way to do this. Here's what I came up with so far:

```
function pullScripts(text) {
  var frag = document.createDocumentFragment()
    , div = document.createElement('div')
    , scriptElements
    ;

  // This is roughly how jQuery finds the scripts when cleaning text
  frag.appendChild(div);
  div.innerHTML = text;

  scriptElements = div.getElementsByClassName('class-for-scripts-that-we-want');

  $('head').append(scriptElements);
}
```

This works well enough, although I haven't tested it on any crappy browsers yet. Regardless, it feels uncomfortable to replicate such basic functionality of jQuery just to avoid one of its features (the special `script` handling). As can be seen in the fiddle, the jQuery object actually does contain the `script`s, but it won't return them with something like `.html()` or `.get()`. **Am I missing some obvious way of doing this?**

*Note: this whole topic will be moot once jQuery's internal `parseHTML` function is exposed*

*Note 2: I've also read [Trying to select script tags from a jQuery ajax get response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4430707/trying-to-select-script-tags-from-a-jquery-ajax-get-response) however the accepted answer is "you can't" followed by "use a regex". Both of which are unsatisfactory*

Comment: Just a note, the first parameter passed into your success callback is the data from the request, not an event

Comment: Doesn't $.load() address this?

Comment: @Austin, thanks. I typed that freehand, knowing I'd mess it up. Christophe: In a way, but if you add a selector to the URL (as I would need to in order to use it) you run into the same problem outlined above.

Comment: In jQuery 1.8.0b1, you can now use the `$.parseHTML()` method to make this easier. `$.parseHTML(xhr.responseText,true)` will give you a jQuery object that includes script elements. You can then extract the script tags and append or execute them after you append the html. If upgrading jQuery isn't an option, maybe you could just take the implementation of `$.parseHTML` and include it as a plugin to your current jQuery.

Comment: It is also common to get this same functionality using regexp, as you have already noted. That is exactly how History.js handles it in one of it's examples. See line 134 and on: https://gist.github.com/1145804

Comment: `$.parseHTML()` returns an array of DOM nodes, not a jQuery object. https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseHTML/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In jQuery 1.8.0b1, you can now use the [`$.parseHTML()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/) method to make this easier.

`$.parseHTML(xhr.responseText,true)` will give you a jQuery object that includes script elements. You can then extract the script tags and append or execute them after you append the html.

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/whole_page.html',
  success: function (data, status, xhr) {
    var $result = $.parseHTML(xhr.responseText,true),
        $scripts = $result.find("script").add($result.filter("script")).detach();

    $('#menu').html($('#menu', $result).html());
    $('#content').html($('#content', $result).html());
    $('head').append($scripts);
  }
});
```

You may have to filter the scripts though to avoid double including jQuery on a case by case basis. It will depend on the content you are loading.

If upgrading jQuery isn't an option, you could just take the implementation of `$.parseHTML` and include it as a plugin to your current jQuery

```
(function($) {
    if (!$.parseHTML) {
        var rsingleTag = /^<(\w+)\s*\/?>(?:<\/\1>)?$/;
        // data: string of html
        // context (optional): If specified, the fragment will be created in this context, defaults to document
        // scripts (optional): If true, will include scripts passed in the html string
        $.parseHTML = function( data, context, scripts ) {
            var parsed;
            if ( !data || typeof data !== "string" ) {
                return null;
            }
            if ( typeof context === "boolean" ) {
                scripts = context;
                context = 0;
            }
            context = context || document;

            // Single tag
            if ( (parsed = rsingleTag.exec( data )) ) {
                return [ context.createElement( parsed[1] ) ];
            }

            parsed = jQuery.buildFragment( [ data ], context, scripts ? null : [] );
            return jQuery.merge( [],
                (parsed.cacheable ? jQuery.clone( parsed.fragment ) : parsed.fragment).childNodes );
        }
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 2):

While I was playing with jQuery (edge) last night on jsFiddle, I wasn't able to use `.find()` and friends on the result of `$.parseHTML()`. The problem was that `$.parseHTML` returns an array of elements rather than a jQuery object, and if you make one with `$()` you're back at the original problem. So, you still can't really use selectors. Not much of a hassle though:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/some_page.html',
  success: function (data, text, xhr) {
    var result = $.parseHTML(data, true)
      , scripts = []
      , i;

    // filter the scripts somehow
    for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        if (result[i].getAttribute('class') === 'good') {
            scripts.push(result[i]);
        }
    }

    $('head').append(scripts);
  }
});​
```

I've made [a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kaen/ZSAeY/3/) for this.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before you should use $.parseHTML that returns an array of nodes.

I have added class 'append-on-ajax-script' on script tag that should be appended on ajax request.

Also I had problems with getAttribute('class') function so my example have some workaround for class checking.

```
<script type="text/javascript" class="append-on-ajax-script">
$.post(
    $(this).prop('href'),
    {'some_data':'some_value'},
    function(data) {
        var script = $.parseHTML(data, true);
        for (var i = 0; i < script.length; i++) {
            //console.log(i, (' ' + script[i].className + ' ').indexOf(' append-on-ajax-script ') > -1 );
            if ((' ' + script[i].className + ' ').indexOf(' append-on-ajax-script ') > -1) {
                // console.log(i, script[i]);
                $('body').append(script[i]);
            }
        }

    }
);
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" class="append-on-ajax-script">
    alert('repeat me on ajax');
</script>
```